# COUNTIFS formula - unique values

Tags: excel, countif

I would like to create one formula that will give me the desired result, which is number of unique IDs with "0" Amount. Below I have two formulas, but since the whole document has a lot of data, I would like to have one formula.

first formula counts how many times ID occurs in column A
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A2,A2,$G$2:$G2,"0")

[image]

second formula counts how many unique IDs have "0" Amount in column G
=COUNTIFS(K2:K18,"1",G2:G18,"0")

[image]

sample of raw data:

```
ID      Amount
100075738   0
100075738   0
27258   312.76
27300   961.59
27372   316.96
27578   769.3
30609   0
33163   573.16
36245   0
36249   3365.6
42026   1563.8
47065   673.12
48966   442.33
100007640   1287.16
100010436   2615.55
100026622   692.44
100028235   1548.4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to the new **`Dynamic Array`** formulas in excel you can use:

```
=COUNT(UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A18,B2:B18=0)))
```

---

If you don't have access to those, you can use this **`Array`** formula instead
 *(Must be confirmed with  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>  +  <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>  +  <kbd>ENTER</kbd> )*

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(B2:B18=0,MATCH(A2:A18,A2:A18,0)),ROW(A2:A18)-ROW(A2)+1)>0))
```

---

Output of both are below in photo along with formula used next to output for reference

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot!  That's what I was looking for :)